# How do I create a PowerShell alias (or function) that contains an option?

Tags: powershell, alias

I'm learning PowerShell, so I'm doing stuff like this a lot:

```
Get-Command | Out-String -Stream | ss child
```

(`ss` is an alias for `select-string`).

I'm getting tired of typing `Out-string -Stream` all the time, so in Unix I'd just create an alias for it. However this doesn't work in Powershell.

- I created it as an alias, and it errored out (I think I understand that).
- I created it as a function, but it swallows all my output
- I created it as a filter, and that also produced no output.

How can I do this?

---

Using *child* as the argument is probably the best way to do this particular task, but I'm really using this as an example to learn how to write PS functions.

I just want the function to replace the 'Out-string -Stream' part, so that instead of:

```
Get-Command | Out-String -Stream | ss child
```

I'll be able to write:

```
Get-Command | oss | ss child
```

I'm guessing I need to use ValueFromPipeline, or the $input variable, like Matt shows.

---

Okay, I got it. I guess I need to explicitly say to read from the pipeline. Instead of:

```
function oss { Out-String -Stream }
```

I need to say:

```
function oss { $input | Out-String -Stream }
```

I wonder how I missed that in the documentation?

Comment: I will poke around and see if I can find an answer to your question. In the meantime however, I suspect that there is a better way to get the same result: Get-Command \*child\*

Comment: In [PowerShell 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=34595), `oss` is pre-defined for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean a function swallows all your output?

I tried this and get the same outputs:

```
function MySS {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param (
        [string] $SearchString
    )
    Process {
        Get-Command | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern $SearchString
    }
}
```

Running Get-Member and GetType on the output return the same form the function and piped command.

EDIT: If you wanted to us other originating functions

```
function MySS2 {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(
                    Mandatory = $True,
                    ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        $input,
        [Parameter(
                    Mandatory = $True,
                    ValueFromPipeline = $false,
            Position = 0)]
        [string] $SearchString
    )
    Process {
        $input | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern $SearchString
    }
}
```

e.g.

```
Get-Command | MySS2 "Get"
get-help get-alias | MySS2 "Get"
```

EDIT: simplest form (select string commented out):

```
function MyOSS {
    param ($input)
    $input | Out-String -Stream #| Select-String "Get"
}
```

EDIT: final edit i think! :-)

I see you figured it out yourself Jonathan - glad to have helped and I didn't know you could use $input without declaring it as a parameter. That's cool.

Comment: 'Swallow my output' means that when I run `Get-Command` I get screens of output written to my screen, but when I run `Get-Command | oss`, I get no output written to screen. (I'm using ISE, if that matters).

Comment: I should add that my function looks like `function oss { Out-String -Stream} ` and then  `filter oss { Out-String -Stream}`

Comment: Do I really need to resort to cmdletbinding just to read from and write to the pipeline?

Comment: No, it'll work without - I always add cmdletbinding when doing a function though - mainly for write-verbose.

Comment: the function function `oss { Out-String -Stream}` doesn't do anything - there's no variable processing etc...

Comment: Yeah, that's what your example made me realize. In Unix-land, if any command in your function reads from the pipeline (i.e. STDIN), then your function will too, without needing to explicitly include "$input |"

Answer (score 1):

FWIW:

- I've been using this `grep` replacement function for, well, as long as I've been using PowerShell :

  `function grep { $input | out-string -stream | sls $args }`
- Current versions of PowerShell (>=3.0) have both an alias for `Select-String` (`sls`) and a shortcut function for `Out-String -Stream` (`oss`). `Get-Command` also has its own alias, `gcm`. Thus the standard abbreviated form for your command is `gcm | oss | sls child`
- Wildcards are allowed in `Get-Command`'s `name` parameter, which means `gcm *child*` basically does it (and is of course much faster)